# Backbone + jQuery .append()

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, twitter-bootstrap, handlebars.js

I've combed through most relevant posts and I couldn't find a similar case. I'm somewhat stumped, hope you guys might figure out the problem.

I'm using Backbone + jQuery + Handlebars + Bootstrap with a REST+JSON API.

I'm trying to build a collapsible view of multiple Items that may contain Texts. There are three levels of collapsing: 1) only the Items, 2) Items + Text titles, 3) Items + Text titles + full Texts.

What should happen is that ItemListView pulls all Items from the API and renders an ItemView for each one. The ItemView is further broken down to two Handlebars templates - the first one for item-specific markup and the other for text-specific markup.

The problem seems to be that the `$("#item" + itemNum)` selector inside `this.model.get("texts").forEach(function(txt, that)` doesn't match anything (or at least `.append()` doesn't add anything).

I've tried changing the selector to `$("item1")` but then the code goes totally barmy, producing a Handlebars template with the title of the first Item's first Text and the content of the *other* Item only Text's text:

```
<div id="item1" class="item in collapse" style="height: auto;">
<ul class="text-list"></ul>

<li class="text-container"><span class="pict text-title collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#text2-1">Otsikko 1</span>
  <span id="text2-1" class="collapse item-text in" style="height: 0px;"><br>Teksti 3</span></li>
</div>
```

Also note the strange `style="height: 0px;"` and `item in collapse` which don't seem to come from anywhere (at least not my templates...).

The API currently returns the following test data (two Items, the first one has two Texts and the second one has one):

```
[{"texts": [{"text": "Teksti 1", "id": 1, },
            {"text": "Teksti 2", "id": 2, }],
  "open": false,
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Asia 1"},
 {"texts": [{"text": "Teksti 3", "id": 1, }],
  "open": false,
  "id": 2,
  "name": "Asia 2"}]
```

I have a View for the whole thing:

```
var ItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
  tagName: 'div',

  initialize: function () {
    _.bindAll(this, 'render');
    this.model.bind('change', this.render);
  },

  render: function (itemNum) {

  // Render item titles

  try {
    var src = $("#item-template").html();
    var itemTemplate = Handlebars.compile(src);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
  }

  $(this.el).html(itemTemplate({
    itemNum: itemNum,
    itemName: this.model.get("name"),
  }));

  // Add texts under titles

  try {
    var src = $("#text-template").html();
    var textTemplate = Handlebars.compile(src);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
  }

  // MOST LIKELY THE PROBLEM:
  var counter = 0;
  this.model.get("texts").forEach(function(txt) {
    console.log(txt.text);
    counter++;        
    $("#item1").append(textTemplate({
      itemNum: itemNum,
      textNum: counter,
      text: txt.text
    }));
  });
```

Just in case, here's the list view:

```
  var ItemListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('#items'),

    initialize: function () {
      _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'appendItem');
      this.items = new Items();      

      this.render();
    },

    render: function () {
      var self = this, p;
      p = this.items.fetch();

      p.done(function () {
        var itemCount = 0;
        _(self.items.models).each(function(item) {
          itemCount++;
          self.appendItem(item, itemCount);
        }, self);
      });
    },

    appendItem: function (item, itemCount) {
      var itemView = new ItemView({
        model: item
      });
      $('#item-list', this.el).append(itemView.render(itemCount).el);
    }
  });
```

...and Handlebars templates:

```
<script id="item-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  <span class="item-title pict" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#item{{itemNum}}">{{itemName}}</span>
  <div id="item{{itemNum}}" class = "collapse item">
    <ul class="text-list"></ul>
  </div>
</script>

<script id="text-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  <li class="text-container"><span class="pict text-title" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#text{{itemNum}}-{{textNum}}">Otsikko {{textNum}}</span>
  <span id="text{{itemNum}}-{{textNum}}" class="collapse item-text"><br>{{text}}</span></li>
</script>
```

...and HTML being rendered:

```
<div class="span2" id="items">
  <div id="item-list"></div>
</div>
```

Thanks! I've been banging my head at a wall for several hours and don't know what to do.

Also, I only did my first Backbone.js code this weekend, so I appreciate any comments on style/design you might have. :)

Comment: When I encounter issues like this I find it's helpful to check to see if the jQuery object contains any elements: `console.log($("#item1").length)`, and also to make sure the string I'm trying to append contains what I think it does: `var parsedTpl = textTemplate({...}); console.log(parsedTpl);`

Comment: Have you tried `this.$(...)` instead of `$(...)`? If your `el` isn't in the DOM yet you need to localize your searches to your `el` rather than looking at the DOM. There's a lot of code there so that's just a wild guess.

Comment: @muistooshort, sorry, I forgot to add one strange thing to the question: when I add `console.log($("#item1", window.parent.document).html());` inside the loop, it returns the following matches:

     null
     null
     <ul class="text-list"></ul>

So, it only finds the element `<ul>` on the third try...? This sounds like the time when I had a head-scratcher with .fetch() before realizing that I need to add a .success() handler. But there isn't any async going on, is there?

When I do the match in the Firefox/Chrome JS console, it finds `$("#item1")` nicely.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I had time to look at this again and found that it was a simple mistake in

```
$(this.el).html(itemTemplate({
    itemNum: itemNum,
    itemName: this.model.get("name"),
}));
```

Changing `.html()` to `.append()` did the trick, unsurprisingly...